# How to hide more than one legend on Chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can I hide two labels on a chart with chart js?

Using this code as an example, I want to hide legend 1 and legend 2, but I only can hide one element

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      // This label is removed in the filter function
      label: 'Legend 1',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    }, {
      label: 'Legend 2',
      data: [11, 12, 33, 4, 2, 3],
    }, {
      label: 'Legend 3',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 195, 255, 0.2)',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        filter: function(item, chart) {
          // Logic to remove a particular legend item goes here
                    return !item.text.includes('Legend 1');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Thank you

**Edit 1**

Just to be clear, I've found how to hide just one legend, but I want to hide more than one.

Like the images bellow
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the Answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080918/hide-first-label-in-legend-in-a-chart-using-chart-js)

Basically what I've done is to insert this statement on options:

```
    legend: {
        labels: {
            filter: function(legendItem, chartData) {
                if (legendItem.datasetIndex === 0 || legendItem.datasetIndex === 1 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            return true;
            }
        }
},
```

I believe that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hide them at the options level, hide them at the label level:

```
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Legend 1',
        hidden: true,
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    }, {
      label: 'Legend 2',
      hidden: true,
      data: [11, 12, 33, 4, 2, 3],
```

Comment: That's hide the series and  makes a dash on the legend. What I want to do is to hide only the legend.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of time to realize for chartjs V3, it's **plugins** inside **options**:

```
options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    filter: function(legendItem, data) {
                        let label = data.datasets[legendItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                        if (typeof(label) !== 'undefined') {
                            if (legendItem.datasetIndex >= 3){
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return label;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72517845/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).